# Wireless, Ethernet and Bluethooth not working with lenovo G5080 under Ubuntu 12.04.5/14.04 64bit

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, wireless, drivers, ethernet

I have Lenovo G50-80 laptop and installed Ubuntu 12.04.05 or 14.04 for 64 bit.
But I can't establish a wireless connection or a ethernet connection.

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev10)
      Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3821]
      Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0041] (rev 20)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3545]

04:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun [Radeon HD 8500M] [1002:666f] (rev ff)

$ rfkill list
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ uname -r
3.13.0-32-generic
```

Which driver do I have to install to connect with wireless and ethernet and from where?

Comment: How about creating a Ubuntu 14.04 bootable USB-stick and see if it supports your ethernet/wireless out-of-the-box? Have you tried that? Or is there a specific reason you need to run 12.04?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mr. MadMike
I am using one erp product which is compatible with ubuntu12.04 so i prefer it.  But as per your suggestion I have check with install Ubuntu 14.04 and with bootable USB using try ubuntu option. I have check with searching additional driver option.
But no success same issue no any connection.  Is there any other way or suggestion?

Comment: This is a very new Qualcomm wireless. There is a new kernel module for it ath10k. But there is a problem with firmware, that should be extracted from Windows drivers. But I see no problems with Ethernet.

Comment: The driver is installed. Post `route -n` and `ping -c 1 google.com`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My wifi Qualcomm Atheros Device \[168c:0041\] (rev 20) doesn't show up and work in Ubuntu14.04.3 on lennovo flex 3 14](http://askubuntu.com/questions/678145/my-wifi-qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0041-rev-20-doesnt-show-up-and-work-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello all I got solution from this ubuntu bug link https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1436940/+index?comments=all
It has not official solution from ubuntu, bug is still pending but I have followed comment #81 & #90 from it's comments and my wifi and wired both are working now. One more point need to share that. After apply solution I got update from ubuntu and I updated my ubuntu but unfortunately I lost my both wifi & wired connection. Again I apply #81 & #90 comment from above bug comments it is working fine now. So after apply fixes take care of new updates for ubuntu.
I have check above with 14.04 64 bit. not checked with ubuntu 12.04. May be above fixes works with ubuntu 12.04 too.