# My wifi Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0041] (rev 20) doesn't show up and work in Ubuntu 14.04.3 on Lenovo flex 3 14

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, lenovo, atheros

I am new on linux systems I have tried some of the relevant solutions, those I could follow up, But nothing yet.Please help me figuring this out.

> Wireless info START

```
Report from: 24 Sep 2015 22:40 EDT -0400
Booted last: 24 Sep 2015 22:21 EDT -0400
Script from: 14 Jul 2015 17:04 UTC +0000
```

> Release

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

> Kernel

```
Linux 3.19.0-30-generic #33~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 22 09:27:00 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Parameters: `ro`, `quiet`, `splash`, `vt.handoff=7`

> Desktop

```
Ubuntu
```

`lspci`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0041] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3545]

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:381e]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

`lsusb`

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:2085 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e300 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b50f Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

> PCMCIA card info

`rfkill`

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`lsmod`

```
iwlwifi               188416  0 
b43                   421888  0 
bcma                   53248  1 b43
wl                   6369280  0 
mac80211              708608  1 b43
cfg80211              524288  4 wl,b43,iwlwifi,mac80211
snd_soc_rt5640         94208  0 
snd_soc_rl6231         16384  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_soc_core          196608  1 snd_soc_rt5640
ssb                    65536  1 b43
wmi                    20480  0 
snd_pcm               106496  8 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller,snd_pcm_dmaengine
ideapad_laptop         20480  0 
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
```

`interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

`ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.177  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:48762 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:29129 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:52576436 (52.5 MB)  TX bytes:5291053 (5.2 MB)
```

`iwconfig`

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

`route`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

`resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search fios-router.home
```

> network managers
>       Installed:

```
    NetworkManager

Running:

root       757     1  0 22:21 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager
```

> NetworkManager info

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           1000 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.177
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1
```

> NetworkManager.statE

```
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true
```

> NetworkManager.conf

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

> NetworkManager profiles

`iw reg get`

```
Region: America/New_York (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
```

> iwlist channels

```
eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.
```

> iwlist scan

```
eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

> module infos

```
[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3165-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-10.ucode
srcversion:     19A5C735A79087003D53D6A
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        48:A3:57:45:53:5D:8D:6F:34:1B:30:C6:3C:3A:A3:85:78:74:3D:0D
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable (default: 1) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

[b43]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/b43/b43.ko
firmware:       b43/ucode9.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode5.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode16_mimo.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode15.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode14.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode13.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode11.fw
license:        GPL
author:         Rafał Miłecki
author:         Gábor Stefanik
author:         Michael Buesch
author:         Stefano Brivio
author:         Martin Langer
description:    Broadcom B43 wireless driver
srcversion:     11BDA0A580599B083FE4F2B
depends:        bcma,ssb,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        48:A3:57:45:53:5D:8D:6F:34:1B:30:C6:3C:3A:A3:85:78:74:3D:0D
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           bad_frames_preempt:enable(1) / disable(0) Bad Frames Preemption (int)
parm:           fwpostfix:Postfix for the .fw files to load. (string)
parm:           hwpctl:Enable hardware-side power control (default off) (int)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (int)
parm:           hwtkip:Enable hardware tkip. (int)
parm:           qos:Enable QOS support (default on) (int)
parm:           btcoex:Enable Bluetooth coexistence (default on) (int)
parm:           verbose:Log message verbosity: 0=error, 1=warn, 2=info(default), 3=debug (int)
parm:           pio:Use PIO accesses by default: 0=DMA, 1=PIO (int)
parm:           allhwsupport:Enable support for all hardware (even it if overlaps with the brcmsmac driver) (int)

[bcma]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/bcma/bcma.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Broadcom's specific AMBA driver
srcversion:     F17244FFF75F9BDF92327ED
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        48:A3:57:45:53:5D:8D:6F:34:1B:30:C6:3C:3A:A3:85:78:74:3D:0D
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     9A49255BA90267D99664757
depends:        cfg80211
vermagic:       3.19.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-30-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     6AE775D26377F997426A49D
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        48:A3:57:45:53:5D:8D:6F:34:1B:30:C6:3C:3A:A3:85:78:74:3D:0D
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-30-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     F28307769349A31F4B24FC2
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        48:A3:57:45:53:5D:8D:6F:34:1B:30:C6:3C:3A:A3:85:78:74:3D:0D
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

[ssb]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/ssb/ssb.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Sonics Silicon Backplane driver
srcversion:     551AE4C23939F7FBED9DA61
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        48:A3:57:45:53:5D:8D:6F:34:1B:30:C6:3C:3A:A3:85:78:74:3D:0D
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
```

> module parameters

```
[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: Y
wd_disable: 1

[b43]
allhwsupport: 0
bad_frames_preempt: 0
btcoex: 1
hwpctl: 0
hwtkip: 0
nohwcrypt: 0
pio: 0
qos: 1
verbose: 2

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00
```

`/etc/modules`

```
lp
rtc
b43
b43
```

> modprobe options

```
[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en
```

`rc.local`

```
exit 0
```

`pm-utils`

`udev rules`

```
[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

`dmesg`

```
[    9.576783] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
```

> Wireless info END

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Ubuntu 16.04 users:
Do not use the dkms or backports, you just need to install firmware and set the parameter using

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.158_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.158_all.deb
```

Reboot

For Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.10 you need backports and firmware

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v4.4.2/backports-4.4.2-1.tar.gz
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
tar -zxvf backports-4.4.2-1.tar.gz
cd backports-4.4.2-1
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot and see if the firmware had issues with `dmesg | egrep -i 'ath|firm`

Edit to add:**Firmware Install**

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.158_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.158_all.deb
```

End of Firmware Install

If you get a new kernel, your wireless will quit working until the new kernel contains the fix, if you notice wifi isn't working after a reboot

```
cd backports-4.4.2-1
make clean
make defconfig-ath10k
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot

Comment: At the end I got the message that the driver should be now installed and please reboot. but after rebooting still the same thing no wifi. when I use the code 'dmesg | egrep -i 'ath|firm' it waits for ever >

Comment: The edit should fix

Comment: I will make an edit later today to add commands to run when a kernel update happens and wifi quits

Comment: That's great!!! What about dkms?

Comment: @Pilot6 I have never attempted to do a dkms on a backport, it would be an interesting project

Comment: It is on ath10k. There is no problem to make. The same as I made for focaltech.

Comment: Please accept the answer, I think you click on a checkmark next to the answer to accept

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks for the bounty, I am working on a DKMS deb file but have a few issues that I am slowly figuring out

Comment: It was hard for me too when I did it first time. It is much easier to start with just `dkms.conf` and install it with `dkms install`. Deb file is a bit tricky. I can do it when I find some time.

Comment: @Jeremy31 Please make it more clear that it is enough just to install the dkms package.

Comment: A member at ubuntuforums, sarthak3 just sent me a PM that the dkms package works

Comment: I used the deb file that you have so kindly provided @Jeremy31. Now, if I update to Ubuntu 15.10, will I have to re-do the step? Will the new drivers for this card be automatically picked up with the deb method?

Answer (score 0):

Testing pre release of Ubuntu Xenial Xerus (LTS, development branch) 28.1.2016 running kernel 4.3.0-7-generic with Lenovo u31-70 laptop.
Ath10k drivers support for "Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0041] (rev 20)" is included, but firmware is missing at the moment.
Please nota that installing the `deb`above will not work because the module is already in the kernel

```
git clone https://github.com/atondwal/ath10k-firmware.git
sudo cp -r ath10k-firmware/ath10k/QCA6164 /lib/firmware/ath10k
cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6164
## Also this module option is needed
echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
# Reboot... or mess with module loading
```