# The Bluetooth driver doesn't work in lenovo flex 3 14. please help me resolving this

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, lenovo

I am using ubuntu latest lts (14.04.3).
My laptop does have Bluetooth and I can use it in windows 8. However in Ubuntu it seems that the OS doesn't recognize the hardware.It is not listed on the top bar, under the Hardware>Bluetooth.

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0041 (rev 20)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3545]
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:2085 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b50f Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:2085 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b50f Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: It might help if you can tell us "how do you know" it isn't working? What are the signs of your problem?

Comment: Please edit your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: it's not showing in the top bar. and it's not listed under all setting>hardware>bluetooth

Comment: Please reconsider the question I have edited the text.

Comment: Are you sure you did not miss anything in `lsusb`.

Comment: This wireless/bluetooth chip is not supported by Linux yet.

Comment: I had the problem with the wireless. I posted here and now it's solved and I amusing the wifi right now.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/678145/my-wifi-qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0041-rev-20-doesnt-show-up-and-work-in
isn't there any way to get the bluetooth work as well?

Comment: But you can see in that answer that there must be `0cf3:e300 Atheros Communications, Inc.` in `btusb`.

Comment: It looks like that driver disabled bluetooth by some way. Try to install kernel 4.3. There is native support ow your wireless adapter. And probably bluetooth will work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wireless/bluetooth adapter is natively supported by kernel 4.3.

The backport you have installed to get your wireless adapter working probably has broken the bluetooth.

Install the kernel this way:

```
mkdir ~/linux-4.3
cd ~/linux-4.3
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3-wily/linux-headers-4.3.0-040300-generic_4.3.0-040300.201511020949_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3-wily/linux-image-4.3.0-040300-generic_4.3.0-040300.201511020949_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3-wily/linux-headers-4.3.0-040300_4.3.0-040300.201511020949_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

and reboot.

You will also need an updated firmware. It has been uploaded to `proposed` already. Install the deb file this way:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/linux-firmware_1.127.18_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.127.18_all.deb
```

This package will get into main repositories in a week or too.

Comment: I see this <Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:e300 Atheros Communications, Inc.>
@Pilot6

Comment: You will need firmware too. See the updated answer.

Comment: I am new to linux. could you please tell me how do I exactly install the deb file from the link you sent. I am really thankfull for your help.

Comment: The deb is already there. I added commands to the answer.