# Ubuntu 15.10 Lenovo Yoga 3 14,no network devices available

Tags: networking, drivers, lenovo, 15.10

I know there were some discussion on this machine about the wireless adapter being hardblocked in 14.04. However, After I installed 15.10, the wireless adapter seems recognized now. It shows "no network devices available" now. However, when I ran lspci, it gave me:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0041 (rev 20)
```

When I ran ifconifg -a, it gave me:

```
Link encap: Local Loopback
inet add:127.0.0.1
```

It seems a different question now so I decided to ask about it.

Any advice?

Edit:

I tried the solution to Lenovo Flex 3 but no luck. I'm a newbie please let me know if anything is needed.

Comment: Plus, the usb wireless adapter is not working either. It used to be working when I was using ubuntu 14.04 alongside with Win 8 64. It can let me connect to wifi but it was either super slow or cannot access internet at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My wifi Qualcomm Atheros Device \[168c:0041\] (rev 20) doesn't show up and work in Ubuntu 14.04.3 on Lenovo flex 3 14](http://askubuntu.com/questions/678145/my-wifi-qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0041-rev-20-doesnt-show-up-and-work-in)

Comment: @Pilot6 I tried it but no luck....

Comment: I am also having a similar problem, on an Acer laptop with the following line in `lspci`:
`0e:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)`

Answer (score 0):

I had what seems to have been a similar problem (wireless, ethernet, USB mouse all not working).  I'm not 100% sure what I did that fixed it, but the issue seems to have been that my kernel headers hadn't installed correctly, I think due to some other installation failures.  (I noticed this because `lsmod` showed a lot fewer modules than I expected.)  I booted to an older kernel, which worked fine, then did `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` (which prompted me to fix broken packages, which I did) and `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.2.0-22-generic` (since I had the `4.2.0-22` kernel).  This apparently caused kernel modules to get installed correctly, and then booting to the new kernel worked.