# Wifi Download speed very slow on 15.04 Ubuntu on Lenovo Z70-80

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, 15.04, lenovo

Initially when I installed Ubuntu 15.04 for some reason the default Wireless card driver did not work,  So I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/678244) answer and make it to work.

Basically using this,

```
echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/09/03/backports-20150903.tar.gz
tar -zxvf backports-20150903.tar.gz
cd backports-20150903
make defconfig-ath10k
make
sudo make install
```

But now for some reason, Wifi connection is very slow and unusable when it comes to downloading 100MB files. But on my Windows the download is lightning fast.

**iwconfig**

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"Easyaccess"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 74:85:2A:6C:F6:38   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=50/70  Signal level=-60 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:112  Invalid misc:417   Missed beacon:0

docker0   no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

**sudo lshw -class network**

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 68:f7:28:aa:d8:ff
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:48 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c4204000-c4204fff memory:c4200000-c4203fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Qualcomm Atheros
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 20
       serial: d0:53:49:e6:ed:91
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=3.19.0-37-generic firmware=atheros-12.0.0.102-fw ip=192.168.2.25 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:51 memory:c4000000-c41fffff
```

**lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev e3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 003e (rev 20)
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev a2)
```

**rfkill list all**

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I am new to Ubuntu, but I can give any Ubuntu check logs if needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my kernel to 15.10's and it works perfectly now. I will absolutely  keep up with this post and update it if I run into any other issues.

[This particular answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/661434/478784) basically solved the issue. But [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/678244/478784) did not work for me.