# No Wi-Fi on Lenovo G50-45

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo

So I bought my son a Lenovo G50-45 for christmas and I'm setting it up (removing Microsoft Windows 10, installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and the essentials) for him...

But there's no wireless networking ("Wi-Fi") available, only "traditional" ethernet!

I know there's an integrated wireless card, so any help getting this going would be great...

Thanks!

--

Edit: As requested, here is the output from Terminal:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0041] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3545]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I tried [another solution for a Qualcomm Atheros device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678145/my-wifi-qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0041-rev-20-doesnt-show-up-and-work-in), however it had no effect... Yes, I restarted the laptop.

Edit 2: Nevermind - Ubuntu had some updates to install after the above; once I had installed those and rebooted a second time, everything started working fine.

Therefore, the original solution stands.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My wifi Qualcomm Atheros Device \[168c:0041\] (rev 20) doesn't show up and work in Ubuntu 14.04.3 on Lenovo flex 3 14](http://askubuntu.com/questions/678145/my-wifi-qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0041-rev-20-doesnt-show-up-and-work-in)