# Wireless doesn't work on Lenovo z50 (with Qualcomm Atheros) on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, drivers, 15.10, atheros

I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 on a Lenovo Z50 laptop and the wireless does not work.

> $ sudo lshw -C network

Gave me *-network UNCLAIMED at first. Thanks to [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678145/my-wifi-qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0041-rev-20-doesnt-show-up-and-work-in) I got the driver installed, but the wireless still doesn't work. Perhaps it's installed, but not running? Above command now returns:

> *-network
>
> ```
>   description: Network controller
>
>   product: Qualcomm Atheros
>
>   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
>
>   physical id: 0
>
>
>   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
>
>   version: 20
>
>   width: 64 bits
>
>   clock: 33MHz
>
>   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
>
>   configuration: driver=ath10k_pci latency=0
>
>   resources: irq:35 memory:f0800000-f09fffff
> ```

Wi-Fi isn't blocked:

> $ rfkill list all
>
> 0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
>
> ```
>    Soft blocked: no
>
>    Hard blocked: no
> ```

And:

> $ lspci | grep Network
>
> ```
>   02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0041 (rev 20)
> ```

And:

> $ dmesg | grep ath10
>
> ```
> [16.259750] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq msi interrupts 1 irq_mode 0 
>
> reset_mode 0
>
> [16.891616] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
>
> [17.009226] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board-pci-168c:0041:17aa:3545.bin failed with error -2
>
> [17.009236] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to load spec board file, falling back to generic: -2
>
> [18.245137] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware crashed! (uuid 8a6a6dc6-db5a-4eb1-9336-9742227d3cd8)
>
> [18.245162] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca6174 hw2.1 (0x05010000, 0x003405ff, 168c:0041:17aa:3545 fallback) fw WLAN.RM.1.1-00141 api 5 htt-ver 0.0 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad
>
> [18.245166] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: debug 1 debugfs 1 tracing 0 dfs 0 testmode 0
>
> [18.247359] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware register dump:
>
> [18.247363] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [00]: 0x05010000 0x000015B3 0x000A012D 0x00955B31
>
> [18.247366] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [04]: 0x000A012D 0x00060330 0x00000016 0x8E605006
>
> [18.247369] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [08]: 0x00000000 0x00400000 0x00400600 0x00000001
>
> [18.247372] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [12]: 0x00000009 0x00000000 0x00931C61 0x00931C7D
>
> [18.247375] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [16]: 0x0096BDBC 0x009286B6 0x00000000 0x00000000
>
> [18.247378] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [20]: 0x400A012D 0x0040E2B0 0x00955A00 0x00404590
>
> [18.247381] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [24]: 0x809287D9 0x0040E310 0x7A5089F8 0xC00A012D
>
> [18.247384] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [28]: 0x809288D7 0x0040E340 0x00000000 0xFFF08040
>
> [18.247387] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [32]: 0x809290FE 0x0040E360 0x00400000 0x00400600
>
> [18.247389] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [36]: 0x80929205 0x0040E380 0x00000000 0x00400600
>
> [18.247392] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [40]: 0x40928024 0x0040E3B0 0x0040D3D0 0x0040D3D0
>
> [18.247395] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [44]: 0x00000000 0x0040E3D0 0x009BB001 0x00040020
>
> [18.247398] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [48]: 0x00401BF0 0x00000001 0x00404B9C 0x00400000
>
> [18.247401] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [52]: 0x40928024 0x0040E3B0 0x0040D3D0 0x0040D3D0
>
> [18.247403] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [56]: 0x4FE22000 0xDCD44CFE 0x910BB90C 0x4CF8CEDB
>
> [19.240193] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to receive control response completion, polling..
>
> [20.240198] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: ctl_resp never came in (-110)
>
> [20.240204] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to connect to HTC: -110
>
> [20.318035] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: could not init core (-110)
>
> [20.318066] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: could not probe fw (-110)
>
> [20.324351] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: cannot restart a device that hasn't been started
> ```

And:

> $ ls /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/
>
> ```
>  board.bin  firmware-5.bin  notice_ath10k_firmware-5.txt
> ```

'dmesg | grep ath10' after firmware change (see answer from Jeremy31):

> ```
> [16.920817] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq msi interrupts 1 irq_mode >     0 reset_mode 0
> [17.807211] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for     
> ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
> [17.816148] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for 
> ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board-pci-168c:0041:17aa:3545.bin failed with >     error -2
> [17.816163] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to load spec board file, >     falling back to generic: -2
> [19.094167] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware crashed! (uuid 326f73d2-
> f4b7-4c80-bef6-4cf8e4c4e57a)
> [19.094180] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca6174 hw2.1 (0x05010000, 
> 0x003405ff, 168c:0041:17aa:3545 fallback) fw WLAN.RM.1.1-00141 api 5 >     htt-ver 0.0 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 
> features ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad
> [19.094183] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: debug 1 debugfs 1 tracing 0 dfs 0 >     testmode 0
> [19.096382] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware register dump:
> [19.096387] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [00]: 0x05010000 0x000015B3 
> 0x000A012D 0x00955B31
> [19.096389] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [04]: 0x000A012D 0x00060330 
> 0x00000016 0x8E605006
> [19.096392] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [08]: 0x00000000 0x00400000 
> 0x00400600 0x00000001
> [19.096394] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [12]: 0x00000009 0x00000000 
> 0x00931C61 0x00931C7D
> [19.096396] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [16]: 0x0096BDBC 0x0092A0E0 
> 0x00000000 0x00000000
> [19.096398] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [20]: 0x400A012D 0x0040E2B0 
> 0x00955A00 0x00404590
> [19.096399] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [24]: 0x809287D9 0x0040E310 
> 0x7A5089F8 0xC00A012D
> [19.096401] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [28]: 0x809288D7 0x0040E340 
> 0x00000000 0xFFF08040
> [19.096403] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [32]: 0x809290FE 0x0040E360 
> 0x00400000 0x00400600
> [19.096405] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [36]: 0x80929205 0x0040E380 
> 0x00000000 0x00400600
> [19.096407] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [40]: 0x40928024 0x0040E3B0 
> 0x0040D3D0 0x0040D3D0
> [19.096409] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [44]: 0x00000000 0x0040E3D0 
> 0x009BB001 0x00040020
> [19.096410] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [48]: 0x00401BF0 0x00000001 
> 0x00404B9C 0x00400000
> [19.096412] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [52]: 0x40928024 0x0040E3B0 
> 0x0040D3D0 0x0040D3D0
> [19.096414] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [56]: 0x4FE32000 0xDCF46CFE 
> 0x910BB90C 0x4CF8CE9B
> [20.092205] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to receive control response 
> completion, polling..
> [21.092078] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: ctl_resp never came in (-110)
> [21.092085] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to connect to HTC: -110
> [21.173790] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: could not init core (-110)
> [21.173828] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: could not probe fw (-110)
> [21.188352] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: cannot restart a device that 
> hasn't been started
> [  249.788200] Modules linked in: rfcomm bnep nls_iso8859_1 drbg 
> ansi_cprng 
> dm_crypt fglrx(POE) rtsx_usb_ms memstick kvm_amd uvcvideo 
> videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops kvm videobuf2_core v4l2_common 
> snd_hda_codec_conexant btusb videodev snd_hda_codec_hdmi 
> snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel btrtl snd_hda_codec media btbcm 
> snd_hda_core snd_hwdep crct10dif_pclmul btintel crc32_pclmul bluetooth 
> snd_pcm aesni_intel snd_seq_midi aes_x86_64 snd_seq_midi_event 
> ath10k_pci(OE) lrw ath10k_core(OE) gf128mul ath(OE) mac80211(OE) 
> glue_helper snd_rawmidi input_leds snd_seq snd_seq_device cfg80211(OE) 
> ablk_helper cryptd snd_timer joydev serio_raw snd edac_core 8250_fintek 
> compat(OE) ideapad_laptop k10temp fam15h_power sparse_keymap 
> edac_mce_amd i2c_piix4 amd_iommu_v2 soundcore shpchp mac_hid parport_pc 
> ppdev lp parport
> ```

Comment: The answer may be in the logs: `dmesg | grep ath10` Please edit your question to add the result.

Comment: Done. What does that tell you?

Comment: It suggests that you may not have the most appropriate firmware. What does this tell us? `ls /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/`

Comment: What does `cat /sys/module/ath10k_core/parameters/skip_otp` show?

Comment: cat /sys/module/ath10k_core/parameters/skip_otp just returns:

Y

Answer (score 0):

This from your dmesg tells me you are using firmware from kvalo's github and not atondwal's

```
fw WLAN.RM.1.1-00141 api 5
```

Atondwal's firmware would have shown

```
fw atheros-12.0.0.102-fw api 5
```

To correct the firmware issue

```
cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1
sudo wget https://github.com/atondwal/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/ath10k/QCA6164/hw2.1/board.bin
sudo wget https://github.com/atondwal/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/ath10k/QCA6164/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin
```

Reboot

You cannot just simply copy antondwal's github into /lib/firmware/ath10k as the firmware from antondwal's QCA6164 directory needs to be in the /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174 directory

Comment: I did the above, but the it didn't seem to work. Want me to post another dmesg | grep ath10?

Comment: Sure, I would like to see what changes occurred

Comment: Lets see `md5sum /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin` thanks

Comment: 8f5303e4b1afc818798425a700139133  /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin

Comment: It still must be the issue as I get `17e0ceea64acf84ca8ef35edeede4098` for antondwal firmware-5.bin md5sum