# Ubuntu 15.10 does not recognize Atheros 0041 wireless card

Tags: wireless, 15.10, atheros

I have a Lenovo with Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4 Wireless Network Adapter. I setup it as dual boot Ubuntu 15.10 and Win10. The wireless card works fine on Win10, but is not recognized in Ubuntu.
Here is some output from my Linux terminal:

```
$ lspci | grep Net
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0041 (rev 20)

$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
...
linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic is already the newest version.

$ dmesg | grep -c ath10k
0
```

Please do not mark this question as duplicate of 
[Ubuntu 14.04 Wireless not working: no network interface. Atheros [168c:003e] device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661424/ubuntu-14-04-wireless-not-working-no-network-interface-atheros-168c003e-dev) because its answer

> This device is supported in Ubuntu 15.10 with the latest update

was incorrect in my case.

Please advice.

Comment: It probably *is* supported in 15.10 by the driver *ath10k_pci* but it likely doesn't have the needed firmware. Check the message log: `dmesg | grep ath10k` Edit your question to add the result and I will propose a solution.

Comment: dmesg | grep ath10k
returns empty

Comment: Please try: `sudo modprobe ath10k_pci && dmesg | grep ath10k`

Comment: sudo modprobe ath10k_pci && dmesg | grep ath10k
also return nothing

Comment: Please run: `lspci -nn | grep 0280` Is your device `168c:0041`?

Comment: $ lspci -nn | grep 0280  <br/>
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0041] (rev 20)

Comment: Here is the process: http://askubuntu.com/questions/678145/my-wifi-qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0041-rev-20-doesnt-show-up-and-work-in