# Can't connect to wifi 15.10 - 168c:0041

Tags: wireless, drivers, 15.10

I just installed Ubuntu Gnome 15.10. Currently I can connect through Ethernet but I can't through wifi. No proprietary drivers show up either. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked before. You can follow the instructions in [My wifi Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0041] (rev 20) doesn't show up and work in Ubuntu 14.04.3 on Lenovo flex 3 14](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678145/my-wifi-qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0041-rev-20-doesnt-show-up-and-work-in/678244#678244) to enable it.