# How to install Qualcomm Atheros WiFi Device Driver which is Missing in Ubuntu MATE 15.10?

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, atheros

> $ lspci -nn
>
> 02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0041] (rev
> 20)

Now i'm using Ubuntu MATE 15.10. I have installed some other Linux Distro. But none of them has driver for this device.

Kernel Version :

> uname -r
>
> 4.2.0-16-generic

Please help me to find driver for Qualcomm Atheros WiFi Device. Please give me a solution.

Laptop : Lenovo G 50-40

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My wifi Qualcomm Atheros Device \[168c:0041\] (rev 20) doesn't show up and work in Ubuntu 14.04.3 on Lenovo flex 3 14](http://askubuntu.com/questions/678145/my-wifi-qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0041-rev-20-doesnt-show-up-and-work-in)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using the following steps.. it works on Linuxmint

wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/nmgb5li6sd6i7ij/backath10k-dkms_2.0_all.deb

dpkg -i backath10k-dkms_2.0_all.deb

Reboot

Comment: But did it work with a 4.2 kernel?  I have seen reports that it doesn't work with 4.2 as stated in your question

Comment: Extremely sorry Sir @Jeremy31 .. I installed Linuxmint 17.3 with                                                                                                                                          
3.19.0-32-generic Kernel ... So WiFi driver is working now. Thank you sir.