# WiFi card not detected

Tags: networking, drivers

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 yesterday and all it's updates as well as I read many solutions on Google for how to get Ubuntu to detect your WiFi card and nothing worked, probably because my WiFi card differs from others' 
I was able to identify the WiFi card model by writing this on terminal:
"lshw -C network"

and this is the model description:

```
"*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: QCA6164 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 20
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f0800000-f09fffff"
```

I was not able in no way to get it working, I tried the additional drivers option it didn't show any unknown driver except for AMD graphic card, I can only access the Internet by Wire or Bluetooth. And yes Ubuntu is up to date I'm clueless about if there's any extras I should be downloading.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I'm newbie at this I'm not sure exactly what you mean but I wrote that in terminal and it gave me this|
"Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6164 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0041] (rev 20)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3545]"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My wifi Qualcomm Atheros Device \[168c:0041\] (rev 20) doesn't show up and work in Ubuntu 14.04.3 on Lenovo flex 3 14](http://askubuntu.com/questions/678145/my-wifi-qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0041-rev-20-doesnt-show-up-and-work-in)

Answer (score 2):

According to the Linux Wireless wiki, you need to have a kernel version of 4.3 or later for this wireless card to work.  Your current kernel is probably 3.19, since you're on a fresh install of 14.04.  In a terminal, type this to see your current kernel version:

```
uname -r
```

Assuming that you have an ethernet connection, you can install kernel version 4.4 by running this command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

Once the kernel install finishes, restart your computer, then follow these instructions from [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1436940):

> 1) Get the latest firmware from https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/archive/master.zip
>
> 2) Unzip this file, and copy the contents of ath10k-firmware-master to /lib/firmware/ath10k.
>
> 3) Rename two of the firmware files like so:

```
cd /lib/firmware/QCA6174/hw2.1
sudo mv firmware-5.bin_SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 firmware-5.bin
cd /lib/firmware/QCA6174/hw3.0
sudo mv firmware-4.bin_WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 firmware-4.bin
```

> 4) Reboot your computer. Run "lshw -C network" to see if your card is recognized.

Comment: Kernel 4.2 does not support this adapter.

Comment: But 4.4 does. `linux-generic-lts-xenial` with appropriate firmware. But that can cause problems for a newbie.

Comment: Can you provide a source for your information?  The link I supplied does state that the 4.2 kernel supports the adapter, but you are correct that additional firmware needs to be installed, and I failed to communicate that.  I will add it to my answer.

Comment: Just look into the source code and you will see that ath10k in ubuntu-wily does not support it.

Comment: The `xenial` kernel will do, but it may cause some problems with building graphics drivers like Nvidia or AMD on trusty. But regarding Wi-Fi it should work, if you stated all correct regarding the firmware.

Comment: I will upvote, if you remove the `wily` suggestion.

Comment: I did a check with the Linux Wireless wiki, and the bug report was incorrect.  The first kernel version to support this device is listed as 4.3 here: https://wikidevi.com/wiki/List_of_Wi-Fi_Device_IDs_in_Linux

Comment: It will be much easier if you learn to read the source code. http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-wily.git/tree/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/pci.c  http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-xenial.git/tree/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/pci.c

Comment: Edited to remove the wily suggestion.  Sorry for providing inaccurate information.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping and sorry for the delayed answer it took me a while because I had no Internet connection, I was able to upgrade Kernel to version 4.4 successfully  & rebooted afterwards, but the bug fix topic was either inaccurate or just theoretical  because I have no right to copy Files into lib/firmware/ath10k according to Linux 
http://s18.postimg.org/ol3fyrmbd/Screenshot_from_2016_04_10_10_32_18.png
And even if it was copied I wouldn't know how to rename the files properly I tried to check the additional drivers again given that I have Kernel 4.4 now, did not work too

Comment: @Zayd: You need to have elevated privileges to move files into that folder, since it is a system folder.  Open your file browser as root (administrator) to move the files there.  Be careful when you are using elevated privileges to modify system files.  Step 3 of the instructions above tells you how to rename the files.  You have to run that command in a terminal window (you can paste into a terminal window using Ctrl+Shift+V, or right-click paste, then press Enter to run the command).

Comment: wily 4.2.0.35.28-generic slows down my computer performance and touch-pad do not work.

Comment: Kernel 4.4* with firmware 1.127.20 works perfect.

Comment: It did not work out.. I think I should report my WiFi card's somewhere so they can keep it in their consideration for next updates...

product: QCA6164 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
 vendor: Qualcomm Atheros

Comment: Okay, I have tried every possible solution and nothing has worked so far, the bug fix you guys posted link of seems logical but new versions of Ubuntu seem not to give you authorization to edit/remove anything in lib/firmware file in no way. It had finally worked when I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 just wanted to let you guys know so if anyone has the same issue to try this solution, knowing that I tried to upgrade Kernel to 4.4 and I did, but still did not work, only by upgrading to 16.04 my WiFi card was recognized

Answer (score 0):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1436940 contains all the info you need to fix it