# Ubuntu on HP Realtek RTL8821CE Wifi card not detected

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

This is my first install of Ubuntu and I can't seem to get Ubuntu to recognize my Wifi card.

I have already gone through a few posts on Ask Ubuntu and google but none of those solutions worked:

- [WiFi card not detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/755302/wifi-card-not-detected)
- [Fix No Wifi Adapter Found](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/08/no-wifi-adapter-found-hp-laptops-ubuntu-18-04/)

I followed both link's instructions without error.

*lshw -C network* returns

```
    WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fea00000-fea0ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: c4:65:16:1e:89:e4
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.0.27 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:31 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fe904000-fe904fff memory:fe900000-fe903fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

The output for the RTL8821CE driver is:

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 5
    Region 0: I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at fea00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
```

Let me know if there's anything else I forgot to post.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

Just copy paste these commands into your terminal and reboot.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall git dkms build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
cd rtl8821ce
chmod +x dkms-install.sh
chmod +x dkms-remove.sh
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

source: [ASK UBUNTU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071299/how-to-install-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-rtl8821ce-on-ubuntu-18-04)