# WiFi does not work: Ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo Z51 Laptop

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, lenovo

I followed the instructions in the top answer here:

[My wifi Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0041] (rev 20) doesn't show up and work in Ubuntu 14.04.3 on Lenovo flex 3 14](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678145/my-wifi-qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0041-rev-20-doesnt-show-up-and-work-in)

But got:

```
(Reading database ... 323177 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack backath10k-dkms_2.0_all.deb ...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 2.0
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Unpacking backath10k-dkms (2.0) over (2.0) ...
Setting up backath10k-dkms (2.0) ...
Loading new backath10k-2.0 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 4.4.8-040408-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.4.8-040408-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.4.8-040408-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.8-040408-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/backath10k/2.0/build/make.log for more information.
```

I have linked the contents of the make.log in the following pastebin: http://pastebin.com/dnuAvDfE

What should I do?

EDIT: I have run 'sudo dkms remove backath10k/2.0 --all' and I got this esult: http://pastebin.com/UVyiZTLp I am still unable to connect.

EDIT: Solved! See Jeremy's comment below

Comment: If you are running kernel version 4.4.8-xx, then the driver is already included. You probably just need the firmware. Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `dmesg | grep ath`. Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Please remove that dkms package `sudo dkms remove backath10k/2.0 --all`  Then reboot.  You must have missed my note on that answer about 16.04 users

Comment: I have done these and I am still unable to connect. I did mistakenly install the backath10k-dkms first though, but after uninstalling and rebooting I still cannot connect. Many thanks for your advices though!

Comment: `echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=Y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf` reboot

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! Can you repost this as an answer so that I can give you one of the green checkmarks?

Comment: may be chili555 can solve your problem definitely

Comment: It's a driver manual installation for your card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 users should not use backports or any dkms package as the 16.04 kernel supports more devices than previous versions.  You need to set the `skip_otp` parameter and install firmware in most cases.  The firmware that works is from https://github.com/atondwal/ath10k-firmware.git

Only use this firmware if you have

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0041] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3545]
```

```
echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=Y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
git clone https://github.com/atondwal/ath10k-firmware.git
sudo cp -r ath10k-firmware/ath10k/ /lib/firmware/
cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6164
sudo cp -r hw2.1/ /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/
```

Answer (score 1):

**|| Step Wise Guide to Resolve the Wifi Issue in Lenovo Z51-70 ||**

---

1. Download the tar.gz file named Wifi-70 from this link - [Wifi70.tar.gz](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhwCxtlb048AhEHjD37uuzUbkjhi)
2. Extract the tar.gz file in your desired location/directory

(eg. /home directory)

```
tar -xzvf Wifi-70.tar.gz -C /home
```

3. Go to the folder named - backports-20150731 in Wifi-70 directory through terminal ; Just right click the folder and open in terminal

Then run the following command (We are just trying to compile the code here)

```
sudo make install
```

4. Once this is done go to the folder named ath10k-firmware-master in Wifi-70

Then run the following below commands

```
sudo cp -R ath10k/ /lib/firmware/

sudo bash -c 'echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=y" > 
/etc/modprobe.d/ath10k.conf'
```

5. Now reboot the system. After reboot run the following command.

(it will throw error if you run without reboot)

```
sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
```

Hope, it will resolve your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

*Steps to try resolve the issue;*

1- open software and updates and click on additional drivers

2- install any drivers relating to your network card

3- reebot system

Additional Suggestions ;

1- open terminal and type -- nm-connection-editor -- and press enter.

2- click the add button - making sure you’ve selected the correct network conection ie WiFi.

*if your unsure on how to update your drivers and firmware there is a pice of software from ubuntu mate called the welcome screen which has a setting on the welcome screen called drivers which will install any firmware and drivers your suystem needs to install;*

type in the terminal `sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-welcome`

then once installed type in terminal `ubuntu-mate-welcome`

then click on > getting started > drivers

hope this helps resolve your issue!

Comment: Additional Drivers only installs Broadcom drivers. It will not be helpful for his Atheros.

Comment: This did not work. I did not install the ubuntu-mate-welcome however because it is large and I was unable to install the drivers through the normal method. As Chili555 said this would not help either. Thank you for your response though!!

Answer (score 0):

Your driver requires firmware that is missing:

```
Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board-2.bin failed with error -2
```

With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible, please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
cd ath10k-firmware/QCA6174/hw2.1
sudo cp  *  /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1
cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1
sudo mv firmware-5.bin_SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1  firmware-5.bin
```

Reboot.

Comment: I got fatal: destination path 'ath10k-firmware' already exists and is not an empty directory.


I tried the next steps: bash: cd: ath10k-firmware/QCA6174/hw2.1: No such file or directory :( (I had al

I managed to get to an equivalent lookin directory, ath10k-firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0, but then got:

mv: cannot stat 'firmware-5.bin_SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1': No such file or directory

Comment: To be sure you are getting the latest files, I suggest you remove your old folder and start again at the git clone step. `sudo rm -r ath10k-firmware` and then start anew.